# How to return a value in a lambda funcion inside andmap

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm learning Racket and I don't know how to return a value in the function inside `andmap` function:

```
(define iguales 0)

(andmap
    (lambda (x y)
        (cond 
          ((eq? (last x) (last y)) 
             (set! iguales (add1 iguales)))))
    casos extension)
```

If I add `iguales` at the end of the `lambda (x y)` function I think it will return a value for every `x` and `y` value.

Where is the right place to put return a value in that lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A body returns the value of the last form.

This:

```
(cond ((eq? (last x) (last y)) 
       (set! iguales (add1 iguales)))
```

returns either `#f` or the result of the `set!` form.

In order to return `iguales` from the lambda in any case:

```
(lambda (x y)
  (cond ((eq? (last x) (last y)) 
         (set! iguales (add1 iguales))))
  iguales)
```

The `andmap` form will then return either `#f` or the length of the shorter of `casos` and `extension` (see why?).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used `andmap` but I could used `ormap` instead. Is there another Racket's function to do what I did? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, what _do_ you want to do?

Comment: `andmap` and  `ormap` do very different things! you cannot use them interchangeably, what are you trying to do? Besides, your code is imperative, maybe what you need to use is a `for-each`... or completely rewrite it in a functional way and avoid that `set!` which seems out of place in (most) Scheme code.

Comment: I want to compare all of the elements of `casos` and `extension` lists, and count what of these elements have equal the last element of them. `casos` and `extension` are lists of lists.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of fold (https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-1.html?#fold) and note that you can provide more than one list.

Comment: I have asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499058/compare-all-the-elements-of-a-list-of-lists-without-using-andmap