# Compare all the elements of a list of lists without using andmap

Tags: racket

I have these two lists:

```
(define casos ’((a 3 15 r +)(l 41 9 -)))
(define extension ’((b 4 5 r -)(c 4 90 d -)))
```

I want to get the number of lists of these two list that have different its last element (`+` or `-`).

To do it, I have used `andmap`:

```
(define iguales 0)

(andmap
    (lambda (x y)
        (cond 
          ((eq? (last x) (last y)) 
             (set! iguales (add1 iguales)))) iguales)
    casos extension)
```

If I run this code with the previous lists, `iguales`will be 1.

I don't think `andmap` is the right way to do it.

Is there a better way to do that without using `andmap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to *count* how many elements meet a condition, then use [`count`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._count%29%29), it's pretty straightforward, and you can pass more than one list as parameter (as is your case):

```
(define casos '((a 3 15 r +)(l 41 9 -)))
(define extension '((b 4 5 r -)(c 4 90 d -)))

(count (lambda (caso ext) (eq? (last caso) (last ext)))
       casos
       extension)

=> 1
```

For this case in particular, `andmap` is not the right tool. In general: avoid using `set!`, most of the time you can do what you want in a functional-programming style. Please take some time to study the [list procedures](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) available in the standard library.

Comment: For Scheme, "SICP" is a fantastic book for learning. Also "How to Design Programs" and "The Little Schemer", which might be easier to pick up.